# What was the point of blocking the robot outbreak using Kill-Ballad?

Tags: robotics-notes

In Robotics;Notes, there is some sort of robot outbreak in the city. They all go out of control and attack what seemed like the city hall.

When Frau tries to hack into the servers to stop the outbreak, she is redirected to the Kill-Ballad game. When Kai beats the enemy, access is given and they manage to stop the outbreak.

What was the point of using Kill-Ballad to block the access to the servers? Couldn't the enemy just say "nah, you don't have access, go away" rather than giving a chance to actually stop the outbreak?

Comment: I don't know for sure why they did so, but in a way it was smart of them to do so. You can never be completely sure if your protection is completely failsafe, so you need multiple layers of defence. So moving the hacker's focus to a game which looks beatable but isn't, in order to make the hacker lose precious time sounds like a plausible option. Even if they try to play the game once, they would have lost time. If it wasn't for his *ability* they would have been caught by the police. But it's probably as Mindwin said. PLOT-reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the game was a defense against fixing the problem.

The guy who started it was one of the people who worked on the game with Frau, so he must have been betting that the person who was trying to gain access would not beat the hacked kill-ballad character, even if it was Frau herself.

(since she made the system she could give herself the rights back to fix the problem but couldn't play kill-ballad well enough to beat the hack)

(It also gave Kaito a chance to save the day ;])

Comment: But why give them a chance? The hacker could simply deny them the access, rather than redirecting them to Kill-Ballad.

Comment: Frau had absolute admin privileges and is a skilled hacker so it would not stop her otherwise.

Comment: But then she would hack Kill-Ballad... The game she coded... Which is far easier.

Comment: Again, I think it falls to Kaito needing to step in, but yeah it shouldn't have stopped her if she just fixed the match.
I think thats just how they wanted it to pan out..

Answer (score 1):

My two cents in four letters: PLOT.

The developer that messed the servers was a kill-ballad fan, and its like 60's batman villain all over: it has to have a trademark.

It also gives foreshadowing of

> the final battle where Kai uses his slow time ability to defeat the boss.

And also led to

> the short romantic fanservice that ended with frau kissing an unconscious Kai.

So from all points, it made sense FROM THE PLOT point of view, to fix the robot riot that way.

Otherwise, like a real world explanation? The guy had some mental disorder. A Savant Idiot of sorts.

But !!! ([click HERE for the real point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-kYiDbG39s))

> WE DIG GIANT ROBOTS!

Answer (score 0):

The main thing was that they brainwashed her colleague which hoaxed Frau and their goal was to everything onto her that she was the one who hacked the company and that she choughed them against humans. They wanted it to look like someone else done job so Committee of 300 hundred will not be discovered.

They used Noah (machine strong enough to create delusions for other people who are unable to see them. It's a lot more explained in Chaos;Head). He was decieved by them to believe he got wife and kid and after Frau told him she does not have wife and child his brain started "deteriorating" and he died. So there were no existing evidence who has done it.